# Is it possible to pass a variable length array as a parameter in C++?

Tags: c++

I do not know the value of V before. It is found within a file I open in the program. It cannot be defined as such `#DEFINE V __`. It does not work as a global variable. The input file changes V based on the contents. Expected the parameters to pass and use the djisktra's algorithm found on Geeks for Geeks.

I have tried declaring V globally, but I am given an error saying "variable must have constant value."

```
void dijkstra(int graph[V][V], int src, int V)
//array function being pasted, error is the V in graph[V]
```

```
//V is defined at beginning of main as 
int V;
```

```
//where V is changed
while(std::getline(file2,newstr))
{
    if(newstr.find(check) != std::string::npos)
    {
        V++;
    }
}
```

```
//where it is passed in main
for(int i = 0; i < V; i++)
{
    size = V;
    dijkstra(array[size][size], i, V);        
}
```

Comment: C++ does not have variable length arrays. Use `std::vector`

Comment: C++ does not have variable length arrays. C does, and some compilers provide them as an extension. Use `std::vector`.

Comment: *"I do not know the value of V"* it is 5, as I -> 1, V -> 5 X -> 10 ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use C-style arrays. Use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and friends from the Standard Library where you can ask for the size if you want to know.

Converted:

```
void dijkstra(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& graph, int src) {
  auto v = graph.size();

  // ... Other code.
}
```

For inserting you can use [`push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back):

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> graph;

while(std::getline(file2,newstr)) {
  if(newstr.find(check) != std::string::npos) {
    std::vector<int> row;

    row.push_back(...);

    graph.push_back(row);
  }
}
```

Then pass it in like a regular variable:

```
dijkstra(graph, src);
```

If all that vector stuff looks really ugly, `typedef` it to something more friendly looking.

Comment: Using raw arrays is generally perfectly fine. Though in this case, one really should use a matrix-class. A vector-of-vector is decidedly sub-optimal.

Comment: @Deduplicator "Fine" is highly subjective here. C arrays have no intrinsic size, you need to pass in data + size pairs, and that can get ugly for multi-dimensional structures. Fully agreed, though, that a proper matrix class is better.

Comment: [This answer contains a simple matrix class.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076668/4581301)

Comment: @user4581301 As a bonus that does 2D emulation, which is allows for a more compact structure with fewer pointers and potential memory fragmentation.

Answer (score 1):

For c style arrays, you need to know the size at compile time. A variable like `int N;` is a runtime value. A variable like `constexpr int N = 9;` is usable at compile time and cannot be mutated.

If you need an array sizeable at runtime, you need some sort of dynamic array. The most common one is `std::vector`.

```
void dijkstra(std::vector<int> graph, int src, int V)
```

```
std::vector<int> graph;
graph.resize(V * V); // vector are resizable

for(int i = 0; i < V; i++)
{
    size = V;
    dijkstra(graph, i, V);        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to pass a variable length array as a parameter in C++.

No.

Variable length arrays are not supported in std C++,  But read on, they have an alternative that is surprisingly better.

---

> I do not know the value of V before it is found within a file I open
>   in the program.

A 1d vector is trivial to create, *after* your code has found V, no compile time constant required.

Early in the startup in one of my programs, the gBoard vector is built using argv[3] and argv[4].  Here is a snippet:

```
  aTermPFN               += argv[1];    // ouput tty, /dev/pts/<argv[1]>
  fillPatternChoiceLetter = argv[2][0];
  aMaxRow                 = stoi(argv[3]);
  aMaxCol                 = stoi(argv[4]);
  userDim                 = true;
```

Clearly, the program has already started ... and V size is easily computed from (aMaxRow * aMaxCol).

I find it easy to access a 1d vector (or 1d array), in row major order, as if it is a 2d matrix, with the following function:

```
// game-board-index: computes index into the single dimension vector
//                   from 2d (row, col) matrix coordinates
size_t gbIndx(int r, int c) { return static_cast<size_t>((r * maxCol) + c); }

// a 2d game board of cells

// 2d access (row major order) implemented using 1d access
Cell_t*  getCell( int r, int c )   { return (gBoard [gbIndx(r,c)]); } 

// 1d access is surprisingly convenient for many functions
Cell_t*  getCell( uint gbIndex  )  { return (gBoard [gbIndex]);     }
```

Sample initialization usage:

```
//              vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv_-- 2d matrix access
gBoard [ gbIndx((midRow+1), midCol)   ] -> setOptionX();
//       ^^^^^^--1d row-major order index
```

A randomized gGoard is trivial in 1d:

void GOLUtil_t::setRandom()
{
   CellVec_t  myVec(gBoard); // copy cell vector

random_device rd;
   mt19937_64 gen(rd());
   shuffle (myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), gen); // shuffle order

int count = 1;
   for ( auto it : myVec )  // randomly mark half the cells
   {
      if(count++ & 1)
         it->setAlive(); // every odd cell
   }
}

---

Note from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector:

"The elements are stored contiguously, which means that elements can be accessed not only through iterators, but also using offsets to regular pointers to elements. This means that a pointer to an element of a vector may be passed to any function that expects a pointer to an element of an array."

---

I was surprised how often the 1d access enabled simpler code.

```
for (auto it : gBoard)
   it->init();        // command each cell to init
```

Summary:

Despite variable-length-arrays (vla) not being supported in std C++, I believe you will find std::vector a better alternative.  And you will find that passing the vector within your code works.